# Problemas para activar "event scheduler" en mysql

Tags: mysql, eventos

necesito actualizar una tabla cada 24 horas, para ello estoy intentando crear un evento en Mysql, pero no logro activar el programador de eventos (event scheduler). Al intentar hacerlo me manda el siguiente error.

> Event scheduler: An error ocurred when initializing system tables.
>   Disabling the event scheduler.

Buscando encontré que una posible solución es editar el archivo my.cnf y agregar la linea event_scheduler=1, pero aun después de hacerlo sigo teniendo e mismo problema.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL usas y sobre qué sistema operativo? ¿Usaste algún instalador junto empaquetado junto con otro software?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con event_scheduler=ON al final del archivo de configuracion de mysql.

[image: event]

Comment: una consulta, el SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=off; tambien funciona? se queda permanentemente activado?